# Question regarding localization of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

I made an exercise that went as follows:
Suppose $R = \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{(xy)}$. Define the multiplicative set $$ S = \left\{ 1 + (xy), x + (xy), x^2 + (xy), \ldots \right\}.$$
In the exercise, I showed that $S^{-1}R \cong \mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}].$
My question is as follows:  Why don't we just define $R = \mathbb{R}[x]$ and consider the multiplicative set $S = \left\{ 1,x,x^2, \ldots\right\}$? Wouldn't we also then get $S^{-1}R \cong \mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$? If so, what is the advantage one gets with the definition used in the exercise, if any?

Comment: No advantage. It's an exercise where you have to notice that $x$ becomes invertible in the ring of fractions, and therefore the ideal generated by $xy$ equals the ideal generated by $y$ (which eventually goes to $0$).

Comment: That's what I assumed. Just thought it was strange (and thus perhaps useful) to throw in something that gets annihilated later on. Thanks !

Comment: If the problem is geometric in origin, you might have been originally dealing with functions on two-dimensional real affine space, and then wanted to restrict to only the axis (this corresponds to taking the quotient $\Bbb R[x,y]\to R$). Then, you might have been interested in functions on these spaces which are invertible on a particular locus (this would correspond to localizing). In the end you have a simpler description of the ring you're working with, but you may want to remember the original perspective when thinking about what the ring "means."